# Hyperref and imakeidx do not work together

Tags: hyperref, indexing, incompatibility, imakeidx

I use `imakeidx` package to generate index in my document. I'd like to add hyperlinks into my Index, but it seems to me that `hyperref` and `imakeidx` do not work together. For example, this code doesn't create linkable index:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color}
```

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=green,
    filecolor=green,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=green
}
\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
Text\index{text}
\printindex
\end{document}

How to fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Load `imakeidx` *before* `hyperref`. Generally, `hyperref` should be loaded last, though there are some exceptions (see [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before) ).

Answer (score 3):

Packages [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and [`imakeidx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx) can be used together by creating a new command, like the one shown in the attached example. It may combine several commands to provide alternate font together with hyper-reference. To simplify entering the words into the index, command `\IN` is introduced. Compilation gives 3 page PDF file with the following index.

Index
ENTRY, 1
entryA, 1, 2
entryB, 2

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=blue}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=1]
\newcommand{\BH}[1]{\large\textbf{\hyperpage{#1}}\normalsize}
\newcommand{\IN}[1]{\index{#1|BH}}

\begin{document}
Text on page 1
\index{entryA|BH}
\IN{ENTRY}
\newpage
Text on page 2 \IN{entryA}\IN{entryC}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this have any advantage over loading `imakeidx` before `hyperref`, like in the accepted answer?  My understanding is that when you load `hyperref`, it does similar new commands in the background.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change package, and use [`splitidx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/splitindex) instead of `imakeidx`