# Creating hyperlinks with imakeidx using cleveref

Tags: indexing, classicthesis, cleveref, imakeidx

I'm using `imakeidx` to create the index of my thesis and I would like to have hyperlinks to the pages that are hereby cited. Unlike [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22012/hyperref-and-imakeidx-do-not-work-together), I'm using the `cleveref` package.

Here is the MWE that reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
This is the first definition:\index{First definition}
\begin{equation}
a=\frac{b}{c}
\end{equation}

\chapter{Second chapter}
This is the second definition\index{second definition}
\begin{equation}
b=a\times c
\end{equation}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Every suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `imakeidx` package must be loaded *before* `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
```

Since `hyperref` is loaded by `classicthesis` this is the correct order.

Comment: Oops, I didn't remember that `classicthesis` loads also `hyperref`! Now it works perfectly. Thank you Enrico, your package is really nice.